# listings - strange behavior using escapsinside (unintended spaces)

Tags: spacing, listings

When using `lstlisting` with `escapeinside`, it seems to produce unintended spaces

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    language=C,
    breaklines,
    frame=leftline,
    numberfirstline=true,
    numbers=left,
    tabsize=4,
    %           xleftmargin = 0pt,
    %           xrightmargin = 30pt,
    %           breakindent = 20pt,
    numberblanklines=true,
    escapeinside={?}{?},
}   
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber      
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode}
\newcommand*\rctnr[1]{%
    \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}
    %       \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    %           \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
    %           \refstepcounter{lstnumber}%
    %       }%
}

\begin{document}
     % example 1
Example 1
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=116, captionpos=b]
if (cmmnd == 31) {    ?\rctnr{118}?
    DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputLow(&DIGITAL_BOOSTC_EN);        ?\label{lhst:A}?
    PWM_CCU8_SetDutyCycleSymmetric(&PWM_BOOSTC_L,XMC_CCU8_SLICE_COMPARE_CHANNEL_1, value * 100);?\label{lhst:B} \rctnr{124}?
    DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputHigh(&DIGITAL_BOOST_DISP);  ?\label{lhst:C}
}
\end{lstlisting}
     % example 2
Example 2
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=116, captionpos=b]
if (cmmnd == 31) {    ?\rctnr{118}?
    DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputLow(&DIGITAL_BOOSTC_EN);        ?\label{lhst:A}?
    PWM_CCU8_SetDutyCycleSymmetric(&PWM_BOOSTC_L,XMC_CCU8_SLICE_COMPARE_CHANNEL_1, value * 100);
    ?\label{lhst:B} \rctnr{124}?DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputHigh(&DIGITAL_BOOST_DISP);  ?\label{lhst:C}
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to change the linenumber... that's worked quite well so far... but escaping into LaTeX obviously produces extra spaces, otherwise I would not get another line, nor would the indentation of the last line be off, as you can see in the second exammple.

Would be great, if anyone could provide some clues on what I am missing here or how to implement a workaround.

Comment: Just write `\label{lhst:B}\rctnr{124}` instead of `\label{lhst:B} \rctnr{124}` (that is, remove the space before `\rctnr`).

Comment: also `\rctnr` always produces a space as you are missing a `%` after the setcounter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don't tell this to egreg!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am sorry for wasting time with this easy errors :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three errors in your code:

1. In the definition of `\rctnr` you missed a `%`
2. At the end of example 1 you wrote `?\label{lhst:C}`. There is a closing `?` missing ...
3. At the end of example 2 you wrote `?\label{lhst:C}`. There is a closing `?` missing ...

Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    language=C,
    breaklines,
    frame=leftline,
    numberfirstline=true,
    numbers=left,
    tabsize=4,
    %           xleftmargin = 0pt,
    %           xrightmargin = 30pt,
    %           breakindent = 20pt,
    numberblanklines=true,
    escapeinside={?}{?},
}   
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber      
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode}
\newcommand*\rctnr[1]{%
    \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}% <=======================
    %       \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    %           \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
    %           \refstepcounter{lstnumber}%
    %       }%
}

\begin{document}
     % example 1
Example 1
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=116, captionpos=b]
if (cmmnd == 31) {    ?\rctnr{118}?
    DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputLow(&DIGITAL_BOOSTC_EN);        ?\label{lhst:A}?
    PWM_CCU8_SetDutyCycleSymmetric(&PWM_BOOSTC_L,XMC_CCU8_SLICE_COMPARE_CHANNEL_1, value * 100);?\label{lhst:B} \rctnr{124}?
    DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputHigh(&DIGITAL_BOOST_DISP);  ?\label{lhst:C}? 
}
\end{lstlisting}
     % example 2
Example 2
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=116, captionpos=b]
if (cmmnd == 31) {    ?\rctnr{118}?
    DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputLow(&DIGITAL_BOOSTC_EN);        ?\label{lhst:A}?
    PWM_CCU8_SetDutyCycleSymmetric(&PWM_BOOSTC_L,XMC_CCU8_SLICE_COMPARE_CHANNEL_1, value * 100);
    ?\label{lhst:B} \rctnr{124}?DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputHigh(&DIGITAL_BOOST_DISP);  ?\label{lhst:C}?
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: thanks a lot to you as well. I must have mixed something up when creating this MWE.